# How to scrape data from Amazon Canada?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape data from amazon canada (amazon.ca). I am using requests and bs4 package to send & parse html data. I am not able to extract the data from the response. Can someone please help me in extracting information from response.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Define headers
headers={
        'content-type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36'
        }

# Amazon Canada product url
url = 'https://www.amazon.ca/INIU-High-Speed-Flashlight-Powerbank-Compatible/dp/B07CZDXDG8?ref_=Oct_s9_apbd_otopr_hd_bw_b3giFrP&pf_rd_r=69GE1K9DG49351YHSYBC&pf_rd_p=694b8fdf-0d96-57ba-b834-dc9bdeb7a094&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-11&pf_rd_t=BROWSE&pf_rd_i=3379552011&th=1'
resp = requests.get(url,headers= header)
print(resp)
```

---

```
<Response [200]>
```

Earlier it was showing `<Response [503]>`, so I added headers, now it is showing `<Response [200]>`. So I am trying to extract some information from the page.

```
# Using html parser
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content,'lxml')

# Extracting information from page
product_title = soup.find('span',id='productTitle')
print('product_title -' ,product_title)

product_price = soup.find('span',id='priceblock_ourprice')
print('product_price -' ,product_price)
```

---

```
('product_title -', None)
('product_price -', None)
```

But it is showing `None`, So I checked what exactly data is present in soup. So I print the soup.

`soup.text`

```
'\n\n\n\nRobot Check\n\n\n\n\nif (true === true) {\n    var ue_t0 = (+
new Date()),\n        ue_csm = window,\n        ue = { t0: ue_t0, d:
function() { return (+new Date() - ue_t0); } },\n        ue_furl =
"fls-na.amazon.ca",\n        ue_mid = "A2EUQ1WTGCTBG2",\n       
ue_sid = (document.cookie.match(/session-id=([0-9-]+)/) || [])[1],\n  
ue_sn = "opfcaptcha.amazon.ca",\n        ue_id =
\'0B2HQATTKET8J6M36Y3G\';\n}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nEnter the
characters you see below\nSorry, we just need to make sure you\'re not
a robot. For best results, please make sure your browser is accepting
cookies.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nType the characters you see in this
image:\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nTry different
image\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nContinue
shopping\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nConditions of Use &
Sale\n\n\n\n\nPrivacy Notice\n\n\n          \xa9 1996-2015,
Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates\n          \n           if (true
=== true) {\n             document.write(\'<img src="https://fls-na.amaz\'+\'on.ca/\'+\'1/oc-csi/1/OP/requestId=0B2HQATTKET8J6M36Y3G&js=1"
/>\');\n           };\n          \n\n\n\n\n\n\n    if (true === true)
{\n        var head = document.getElementsByTagName(\'head\')[0],\n   
prefix =
"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/csminstrumentation/",\n
elem = document.createElement("script");\n        elem.src = prefix +
"csm-captcha-instrumentation.min.js";\n       
head.appendChild(elem);\n\n        elem =
document.createElement("script");\n        elem.src = prefix +
"rd-script-6d68177fa6061598e9509dc4b5bdd08d.js";\n       
head.appendChild(elem);\n    }\n    \n\n'
```

I checked the output throughly, but I didn't found any data available in the response, I even tried to do the same and checked in resp.content, but didn't found any data. Also I validated the url, the url is valid too. I even tested above script by adding public proxies, but still no output.

Can someone please help me extract information from the url or any other way to get it done?.

Comment: The text told you that you has been banned.You could wait a moment and retry it .And your code is nearly correct.(You may need to use `product_title.text` and `product_price.text`).

Comment: As the output indicates, you've been detected as a robot. You  may use more detailed headers (changing the User Agent ...)

Comment: @SebastienD  I tried changing different user-agents in the headers. But the output is still showing same with that robot text message.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'content-type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
}

url = 'https://www.amazon.ca/INIU-High-Speed-Flashlight-Powerbank-Compatible/dp/B07CZDXDG8'
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'lxml')

# Extracting information from page
print('product_title -', soup.find('span', id='productTitle').text.strip())
print('product_price -', soup.find('span', id='priceblock_ourprice').text.strip())
```

The code yields:

```
product_title - INIU Power Bank, Ultra-Slim Dual 3A High-Speed Portable Charger, 10000mAh USB C Input & Flashlight External Phone Battery Pack for iPhone Xs X 8 Plus Samsung S10 Google LG iPad etc. [2020 Upgrade]
product_price - CDN$ 60.66
```